# How to interpret /proc/mounts?

Tags: linux, memory, filesystems, hardware, embedded-linux

When i do the following.

```
"cat /proc/mounts".
tmpfs /export/ftp/import tmpfs rw,relatime,size=102400k 0 0
tmpfs /export/ftp/export tmpfs rw,relatime,size=10240k,mode=755 0 0
```

The documentation of embedded device said that import and export are located in DRAM

However in other equipment

```
ubi18_0 /nvdata1/temporary-download ubifs rw,sync 0 0
ubi18_0 /export/ftp/import ubifs rw,sync 0 0
ubi18_0 /export/http/import ubifs rw,sync 0 0
tmpfs /export/ftp/export tmpfs rw,size=10240k,mode=755 0 0
```

The documentation of embedded device said that  import is located in NAND and export are located in DRAM.

I really do not know what resides in DRAM, NAND, NOR.

The basic knowledge i have in our equiment is that
NOR has u-boot.
NAND has kernel and rootfs.

Comment: Linux [tmpfs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tmpfs) are technically not in DRAM, but in the virtual memory (in particular, could use *swap*).

Comment: Thanks Basile. Does it mean that import and export are present in tmpfs? and hence import and export are located in virtual memory?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

### Format of `/proc/mounts`

The 1st column specifies the **device** that is mounted.
The 2nd column reveals the **mount point**.
The 3rd column tells the **file-system type**.
The 4th column tells you if it is mounted **read-only (ro)** or **read-write (rw)**.
The 5th and 6th columns are **dummy values** designed to match the [format used in `/etc/mtab`](http://www.brunolinux.com/02-The_Terminal/Fstab_and_Mtab.html).

More details on filesystem mount-points are available [here](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/4/html-single/introduction_to_system_administration/index#s2-storage-fs-mounting).

---

```
tmpfs /export/ftp/import tmpfs rw,relatime,size=102400k 0 0
tmpfs /export/ftp/export tmpfs rw,relatime,size=10240k,mode=755 0 0
```

**Meaning** : Two independent **tmpfs**-es  are mounted at both `/export/ftp/import` and `/export/ftp/export`. Any data stored into these directories is lost upon rebooting the kernel. [**tmpfs** is essentially a ramdisk-like construct](http://www.cs.rit.edu/%7Evcss544/tmpfs.pdf) that stores data in the RAM. Technically speaking tmpfs is mapped into virtual memory which uses RAM and swap (if present).

---

```
ubi18_0 /nvdata1/temporary-download ubifs rw,sync 0 0
ubi18_0 /export/ftp/import ubifs rw,sync 0 0
ubi18_0 /export/http/import ubifs rw,sync 0 0
tmpfs /export/ftp/export tmpfs rw,size=10240k,mode=755 0 0
```

**Meaning** : The same "partition" on the NAND device (`ubi18_0`) is mounted at 3 different mount-points. [**ubi** is a intermediate file-system layer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UBIFS) that simplifies and optimises I/O with the underlying flash media devices. Also a temporary filesystem is mounted at `/export/ftp/export`.

Comment: Thanks TheCodeArtist.
So my understanding is as follows?
1)The device tempfs with file system tempfs is mounted at /export/ftp/import with read write permission.
Or in other words,
The device tempfs using file system tempfs  can be accessed using the directory(/export/ftp/import) and there is read wire permission to it

2)The device tempfs using file system tempfs  can be accessed using the directory(/export/ftp/export) and there is read wire permission to it

Comment: And in other device,
1)the NAND device (ubi18_0) using file system ubifs can be accessed using the directory(/export/ftp/import,/export/http/import,/nvdata1/temporary-download) with read write access.
2)The device tempfs using file system tempfs can be accessed using the directory(/export/ftp/export) and there is read wire permission to it.

But what is the use? Why is it done like this? I think i need to read about filesystems and mounting first before i ask more questions.
And i think my question is wrong.
Should it be as follows? 
"How to find if a device is mounted in DRAM or NAND or NOR?"

Comment: Yes. Note that both are independent. And writing into one does NOT update in the other. i.e. they are multiple entities of type tmpfs. In contrast is the `ubi18_0` in which writing using any of the mount points will reflect in the other mount-points.

Comment: could you explain more what you mean by *device*? is it the same as char device modules?

Comment: **device** = block device. FYI, there are 3 common classes of devices char, block and network. Storage media are usually enumerated as block devices.

Comment: The fourth column is more than just whether it's ro or rw, right?  The arguments that were given to mount, or some such?

Comment: @msouth Yes, the 4th column is a comma-separated list of flags used to mount that particular mount-point.

Comment: Is this missing a citation to https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/4/html/reference_guide/s2-proc-mounts?

Comment: Done. Added a link to the detailed [Mounting File Systems](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/4/html-single/introduction_to_system_administration/index#s2-storage-fs-mounting) section.

Comment: `tmpfs` essentially isn't a real [device file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Device_file)
 - it's a part of the RAM. What you write under the mount point will be written to RAM.