# java api to receive notifications when a file system is mounted

Tags: java, notifications, filesystems

I am looking for a Java API that will allow registering for file system mount events, i.e. when a file system is mounted or dismounted.  Specifically I want to know when a file system on removable USB devices is available, and also know exactly what type of USB device it was.

The udev subsystem provides notifications on USB plug and unplug events by default but not specifically when the file system on the device is available.  It is possible to create udev rules that can do this in pieces, e.g. create a directory and execute a program when devices are added and removed.  But my experience with udev rules is that the syntax is arcane and they are fragile and not simple to debug.

I've installed usbmount per this post:

https://serverfault.com/questions/414120/how-to-get-usb-devices-to-automount-in-ubuntu-12-04-server

though I believe the devices were automouting by default.

As an alternative I constructed a JDK 7 WatcherService on /media which can detect changes in /etc/mtab.  This works but I have seen cases where the file systems on some USB devices are still not ready - meaning that attempts to read the directory throw an Exception - even after the entry in /etc/mtab is made.  I added a timer to sleep for a configurable number of milliseconds and in most cases a 100ms wait time works but not 100% of the time.  What this means is that increasing this wait time is not an absolute guarantee nor deterministic.

Clearly at some low level the mount event is being generated because the Nautilus pop-up window gets displayed.  I had a case of one flash drive that would put the Nautilus icon in the launch pad menu but it would not mount until the icon was clicked open.

I've also looked at these options:

- tailing /var/log/syslog;  this may be the next best option.  I see lines like the following:

:Dec  2 08:58:07 fred-Inspiron-530 udisksd[1759]: Mounted /dev/sdk1 at /media/fred/USB DISK1 on behalf of uid 1000

I am going to try a WatcherService here to see if the same timing issue exists, i.e. is the directory readable once this message is written.

- jlibudev [ github.com/nigelb/jlibudev ] Much better Java API to udev subsystem than writing rules but it still falls short in that you still have to piece a number of different events together.  NB: jlibudev depends on JNA [https://github.com/twall/jna] and purejavacomm [ github.com/nyholku/purejavacomm, sparetimelabs.com/purejavacomm/purejavacomm.php]  both of which are pretty useful in their own right.
- lsusb provides details on the usb device but nothing about where it is mounted.

Ideally I would like a simple API that would allow registering for file system mount/unmount events using the standard Java event listening pattern.  I want to believe that such an API exists or is at least possible given that at a macro-level the net effect is occurring.  I am still scouring the JDK 7 and JDK 8 APIs for other options.

Any and all pointers and assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Since there's no OS-agnostic way to deal with mounting filesystems, there's definitely no JDK API for this. I'm guessing this problem is not dealt with much (not a lot of programs deal with mounting filesystems directly), so it's unlikely that there's any prebuilt library out there waiting for you.

Of the approaches you mentioned, they all sound roughly equal in terms of how platform-specific they are (all Linux-only), so that just leaves performance and ease of coding as open questions. Regarding performance, running `lsusb` more than once a second is (a) a giant hack :-) and (b) fork+exec is slow compared to running something in-process, and tailing the event log will create a lot of (unpredictable) work for your program that is not related to USB mounts as well as making your implementation more fragile (what if the message strings change when you upgrade your OS?). Regarding ease of programming, either using `jna` or JNI to call into `libudev` or a `WatcherService` on `/media` sound about equal -- using `libudev` seems like the most portable option across Linux distros / user configurations (I'm guessing that's what Nautilus uses).

However, for simplicity of implementation that will work for 99% of users, it's hard to do better than a `WatcherService` on `/media`. To help ensure that the filesystem is available before use, I would just use a loop with some kind of randomized exponential backoff in the amount of time to wait between attempts to read the directory -- that way you never wait way longer than necessary for the filesystem to mount, you aren't burning tons of CPU waking up and trying to read, and you don't have to pick a single timeout number that won't work everywhere. If you care enough to ensure you don't tie down a single thread sleeping forever, I'd use a `ScheduledExecutorService` to issue `Runnable`s that try to access the filesystem, and if it's not available schedule themselves to run again in a bit, otherwise alert your main thread that a new filesystem is available for use using a queue of some kind.

**Edit**: I just learned that you could also watch for updates to the `/proc/mounts` file. Hopefully since the kernel is responsible for updating this file things only show up when they're fully mounted, although I don't know for certain. For more details, [How to interpret /proc/mounts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18122123/how-to-interpret-proc-mounts) and [the Red Hat docs](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/4/html/Introduction_To_System_Administration/s4-storage-mounting-proc.html) were useful.